# Give the definition of the degree of a polynomial in $n$ variables and definition of a line in $\mathbb R^3$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, complex-analysis, polynomials

Here is a question I am trying to solve.  $$f(x_1, \dots, x_n) = \sum_{i_1 =0}^{a_1} \dots \sum_{i_n =0}^{a_n} c_{i1\dots i_n} x_{1}^{i_1} \dots x_{n}^{i_n}$$

1. Give the definition of the degree of a polynomial in $n$ variables with real coefficients.
2. Give the definition of a line $\mathcal l$ in $\mathbb R^3$

**My Attempt** For possible real coefficients $0,1,2, \dots$ our polynomial is of the form $$a_0 + a_1 X + a_2X^2 + a_3 X^3 + \dots + a_n X^n$$ Therefore, there are $n+1$ degrees.

And the line $\mathcal l$ in $\mathbb R^3$ I defined as $$f(x,y,z) = ax + by + cz +d =0$$

**Is my approach correct ? Any hint or better approach is appreciated.** Thanks!

Comment: Your solution is incorrect. I suggest reading your lecture notes or the textbook.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Thank you so much for the comment. Please can you suggest a hint. It will really help. Thanks!